# Чат между p2p клиентами за двойным NAT

Tags: c++, qt, nat, p2p, upnp

Как сделать чат между p2p клиентами за ***двойным*** NAT?

- Вариант 1: Все машины с NAT поддерживают UPnP.
- Вариант 2: Только одна сторона может задействовать UPnP.
- Вариант 3: UPnP никому не доступен.

Язык/платформа разработки: Qt С++ (QtCreator + MinGW, Windows).

Comment: В любом случае, Вам нужен сигнальный сервер, что  бы клиенты смогли узнать друг о дружке.

Если хотя бы одна с машин поддерживает UPnP - проблем нет. Она стартует как сервер и вторая подключается к ней. Другое дело, если UPnP нет. Тут нужно пробивать нат (NAT hole panching). Если только с обеих стороне что то отличное от симмитничного ната - все достаточно возможно.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример (C++ или C++ Qt код) либо реквеста на UPnP, либо реквеста к STUN-серверу? Потому что гугл полон абстрактных рассуждений, а кода нет, увы. Я этот вопрос юзаю уже больше времени, чем многие здесь на сайте обретающиеся программируют. И, как вы думаете, я чего-то ещё не знаю о сигнальных серверах, STUN'ах, TURN'ах, ICE и т.д. Помогите кодом, а не набивайте себе репутацию на сайте, отписавшись мутной абстракцией.

Comment: да, гугл полон.Но сложно найти то, если не знаешь что. Вот описание, как работает UPnP - https://habrahabr.ru/post/279969/ . Там же описан NAT-PMP, который на порядок проще (пара UDP запросов и порт открыт). Если хочется готового - http://miniupnp.free.fr/libnatpmp.html - готовая либа.

Но если нужно именно полноценное решение, смотрите на [tox](https://github.com/nurupo/ProjectTox-Qt-GUI).

Comment: Необходим минималистичный код, а не библиотека-дурной-комбайн (как привыкло американское быдло - везде пихать слоноподобное "100500-в-1 решение"). Можете черкнуть хотя бы пять-шесть срок C++ или C++Qt кода (или хоть алгоритм псевдокодом обозначьте), как *программно* хоть запросить UPnP "услугу", если таковая не отрублена на роутере. Статья, на которую вы сослались, ещё давно мне маячила перед глазами и раздражала тем, что там точно так же уходят в общие рассуждения - скорее всего, именно ввиду неспособности писать код. И автора, тут же, заметьте, обломал юзер AlexandrDP (см.) да и другие тоже.

Comment: Или, если не жалко, покажите по кусочку разных вариантов обхода того случая, на который указал автору-хабровчанину юзер AlexandrDP и который (по моей инсайдерской информации, а я имею доступ к статистике провайдеров, по крайней мере, Украины - с её 45 млн. населения) закрывает до 80-90% случаев частного пользования интернетом: имеется в виду ситуация нахождения за фактически *двойным* NAT. И в такой связке двух NATов второй, что смотрит наружу, UPnP как правило не поддерживает, равно как и NAT-PMP. Вот сделайте доброе дело: дайте семплик кода, как пробиться? Может, туннель какой, ICMP или DNS?

Comment: У меня есть некоторые наработки на  тему UPnP, но это не пять-шесть строк кода. Это тысячи строк кода. Но дать точно не смогу - это часть бизнес приложения и закрыто по NDA. NAT-PMP - тут проще, но нужно искать дома простой код, может чего  то и найду.

Двойной нат я не пробовал проходить, тут ничего не скажу.  Но могу посоветовать посмотреть в сторону [udt](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) - там в примерах есть минимальный код для пробивки ната и передачи файла.

Comment: А вы смогли бы поделиться хотя бы в словесной формулировке (а не примером из того кода), как вы решил задачу UPnP-пробива для ваших бизнесменов? Просто словами суть фичи (идеи ведь и рационализации не подпадают под действие закона о защите интеллектуальной собственности, только конкретная реализация в коде или механизме подпадает). Может, вы могли бы мне приватно на мейл ответить (aversilov@gmail.com), прошу вас.

Comment: используются все доступные методы - начиная с stun, udt (пример  был выше) и заканчивая проксями вида coturn. На почту точно отвечать не будут.

Comment: А не могли бы разъяснить концепцию coturn? Это тоже сервер, специализирующийся на прогоне через себя трафика пиринговых или, конкретней, воайпишных клинтов? И разумеется - с авторизацией и за деньги? Или нет?

Comment: Вообще, вы строили когда-либо подлинно децентрализованную сеть, подобную I2P, ZeroNet или RetroShare? И что можете сказать об этих трёх приведённых мною примерах? Есть в чем покритиковать их реализацию, или вы взяли бы на себя смелость рекомендовать их подход? Видели ли вы их код на гитхабе, - это хоть частично то же, что и делали вы, или же ваша задача была на порядок проще, поскольку толстосумы ваши запросто могли платить деньжищи за аренду сигнальных серверов (а то и содержат свои)?

Comment: То есть, подытоживая, всё же: вы full distriduted сеть делали когда-то? Если да, то просто подскажите - какие именно технологии при каких ситуациях (реальных, в "полевых" условиях) следует применить для пробивки пирами хотя бы 90% встречающихся барьеров?